# Kotlin instance counter with destruct

Tags: kotlin, memory-management, instance

I have a class that i want to keep track on the number of instances created. I used a static variable that increments inside the constructer. Is there a way to decrease the number when setting a variable holding an instance to null.

Some languages have deinit or destructors. I know Kotlin doesn't have these is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: What are you counting exactly? The number of instances of that type in memory or the number of variables holding a reference of that type? The latter is impossible. The former is doable but is a *really* weird thing to do. This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is your ultimate goal by doing this?

Comment: Creating an object only happens once. So, decrementing a counter when a reference to that object is removed is not the opposite of creating the object, as there can be many references to the same object. If you want something similar to a C++ smart pointer, then you're out of luck. If you just want to react to when the object is garbage collected, and you're targeting the JVM or Android, then you can make use of the `java.lang.ref` API (not sure about other platforms). Though note _when_ an object is garbage collected is not defined. That all said, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Probably the closest Kotlin idiom is the way that you can use [`use()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) to ensure that [Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) resources always get closed.  (A standard-library equivalent of Java's try-with-resources.)  That seems to a fairly common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

No, the JVM doesn't allow that. In fact, the JVM doesn't even know the number of instances itself, the GC only checks *whether* or not it's referenced from somewhere.

The only thing you could do is manually increase it every time or use lambda expressions that increase the counter as long as you use the variable:

```kotlin
var instanceCount = 1 private set
private val theInstance: InstanceType = TODO()//never use it outside here

//note that this is not thread-safe
fun <T> useInstance(usage: (InstanceType) -> T): T{
    try{
        instanceCount++
        return usage(theInstance)
    }finally{
        instanceCount--
    }
}
```

```kotlin
useInstance {
    doSomething(it)
}
```

If you do this, make sure the references never escape the lambdas.